# Compute the area of that part of the surface of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ cut out by the surface $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

I need help, I'm studying the area of surfaces using double integrals, I attempted to solve this exercise but I'm having trouble. The problem is to compute the area of that part of the surface of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ cut out by the surface $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. This exercise is from  the book "Problems-in-Mathematical-Analysis-Demidovich".

I know that the equation of the sphere is $z = \sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$ , and  $\frac{dz}{dx} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2)}}$ , and $\frac{dz}{dy} = -\frac{y}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}$.
Then I have to use the formula $S = \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dy}\right)^2}$.
Here I'm having trouble, I don't know why the solution guide multiplies the formula $S$ by $8$.

Can the somebody explain me why is this, please.

Comment: Because there are 8 octants and you're doing just that portion in the first octant ($x,y,z\ge 0$). Also, your second equation defines an elliptical *cylinder* (with lines parallel to the $z$-axis).

Comment: [Highly recommended.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Eliminate x to find that two planes

$$ \frac{y}{z}= \frac{ \pm\, b}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}} $$

cutting along $x$ axis demarcate the area you are computing.. due to symmetry of $x-,y-$ axes only one of four upper octants need be considered.

The quantity under radical sign is the secant factor.. by which projected area is to be multiplied to go *from projected area to true area*.

You could as well have used the formula:

$$  S = \sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{dy}{dz}\right)^2} $$